# What are some ways to simulate a Continue statement in VBA?

Tags: vba

Since VBA does not have a Continue statement (or anything of that nature), what is another way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: what about that old standby the goto statement?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it in languages that don't offer a Continue statement is to simply wrap the remaining code block in an `if` condition.

```
For i=1 to 10
    'some code here
    If I_want_to_finish_this_loop
        'do your thing
    End If
Next i
```

This avoids the use of a Goto, and your only cost is to reverse the condition.

If you have more than one place where you need to Continue, your best bet is to place a single Continue label in your code, and Goto it.

```
For i=1 to 10
    'some code here
    If I_dont_want_to_finish_this_loop
        Goto Continue
    End If
    'finish the loop
:Continue
Next i
```

Comment: and if there are multiple places you want to jump to the end of the loop?

Comment: Multiple `if` statements.

Comment: Surely you jest, Mr. Harvey!

Comment: All other options are more complex.

Comment: The goto statement is not complex.

Comment: Too hard to follow, ugly, blah blah blah.  You'd seriously prefer multiple Goto's (and the necessary labels) to nested `if` statements?

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/what-dijkstra-said-was-harmful-about-got/228700940

Answer (score -2):

One way is using an enclosing Do...Loop. Of course, this won't work inside another Do...Loop, but we run into that in most programming languages.

```
For i=1 To 10
    Do 
        'Do everything in here and

        If I_Dont_Want_Finish_This_Loop Then
            Exit Do
        End If 

        'Of course, if I do want to finish it,
        'I put more stuff here, and then...


    Loop While False 'quit after one loop
Next i
```

Comment: Arguably, the second `exit do` should be removed and `loop until true` or `loop while false` should be used instead.